# PHP string operation - strip .jpg extension

Tags: php, joomla

I have the following php:

```
               <?php 
            $image_directory = JPATH_SITE . '/images/site/';
            $images = JFolder::files($image_directory);
            foreach($images as $image) {
              echo '<li><img src="/images/site/'.$image.'">
                    <p class="slidecaption">'.$image.'</p></li>'; 

            }
          ?>
```

So $images ends up being 1980.jpg (for example). How can I perform an operation on this string and strip the ".jpg" and output for the slidecaption paragraph?

Many thanks for your time.

Comment: When PHP provides a [built-in function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php
) specifically for this purpose, use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have every time the same extension then you can use `str_replace`.

```
str_replace('.jpg','',$image);
```

If you have some other more extensions you can do it with a regex something like this:

```
$imageName = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $image);
```

Comment: What if it's in the file name more than once? Grabbing the last . In the string and everything after it would probably be better in the long run

Comment: When there is a .jpg twice in your string then it will remove both of them and this happens only if there is something wrong and you have to times the file extension. But then your name is correct.

Comment: That is really wrong... basename don't remove the file extension ;)

`echo basename("test.jpg");` and when you define a suffix as `.jpg` then its the same like the str_replace. http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php